# Get usage disk of a Windows process by name in Python

Tags: python, windows, process, disk-io

[image]

I would like to create a script that wait until a specific process has 0 MB/s of disk usage.

```py
import time
import psutil


def get_process(name):
    process = None
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        if name in p.as_dict()["name"].lower():
            process = p
    return process


def wait_process(name):
    process = get_process(name)
    if process:
        while process.disk_usage() > 0:
            time.sleep(5)


wait_process("firefox")
```

I tried the psutil module but it seems we can't get disk usage by process.

**EDIT**

I tried this but I get irrelevant number.

```py
def process_disk_usage(process_name: str) -> float:
    # process = None
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        if process_name.lower() in p.as_dict()["name"].lower():
            r_bytes = p.io_counters()[2]
            w_bytes = p.io_counters()[3]
            t_bytes = r_bytes + w_bytes
            return t_bytes / (1024.0 * 1024.0)
    return None


def wait_process(process_name: str) -> None:
    while process_disk_usage(process_name) > 0:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
 p = psutil.Process()
 io_counters = p.io_counters() 
 disk_usage_process = io_counters[2] + io_counters[3] # read_bytes + write_bytes
 disk_io_counter = psutil.disk_io_counters()
 disk_total = disk_io_counter[2] + disk_io_counter[3] # read_bytes + write_bytes
 print("Disk", disk_usage_process/disk_total * 100)
```

Answered here: [How to get current disk IO and network IO into percentage using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357887/how-to-get-current-disk-io-and-network-io-into-percentage-using-python)

Comment: I can't get the same result as in the Windows Task Manager. I would like to get the process disk usage in MB/s.

Comment: @0lan Maybe you can just use powershell ? (Call powershell script from python)